# dynamically change x and y coordinates in QT creator

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I wish to pass x and y coordinates of an ellipse dynamically in QT. I have tried the following, and it appears that the `setPos(x, y)` function does not actually transform the ellipse until after `on_pushButton_2_clicked()` returns.

I have two buttons, `pushButton1` and `pushButton2`, the first is to create the ellipse (and ensure another does not get created once it is called) and the other is supposed to change the passed coordinates.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int hasRun = 0;
    while(!hasRun)
    {
    QBrush green(Qt::green);
    QBrush blue(Qt::blue);
    QPen blackPen(Qt::black);
    blackPen.setWidth(2);
    ellipse = scene -> addEllipse(10, 10, 25, 25, blackPen, green);
    hasRun = 1;
    flag = 1;
    }
}

void MainWindow::change(int x, int y)
{
    ellipse->setPos(x, y);
    cout << "width: " << ui->graphicsView->width() << endl;
    cout << "height: " << ui->graphicsView->height() << endl;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 25)
    {
    change(i, i);
    Sleep(200);
    i++;
    }
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are blocking the UI thread with your sleep operation, meaning that UI never gets redrawn, so you don't see your UI updating until the clicked function returns.

The easiest way to work around this is to use QTimer [1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html), which allows you to schedule an event in the future. When the timer expires (timeouts), it will call your event handler. However, it will not block the UI thread while it is waiting. You could use something like this to achieve the desired animation effect:

```
auto timer = new QTimer(this);

// Define the timeout slow for the timer.
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [timer, ellipse]() {
  auto x = ellipse->x();
  auto y = ellipse->y();

  // If we have reached our target position, stop the timer.
  if (x == 25) {
    timer->stop();
    return;
  }

  // Otherwise update the position.
  ellipse->setPos(x + 1, y + 1);
});

// Start the timer. The timeout slot we defined above will be called every ~200ms.
timer->start(200);
```

An even better way to do this would be to use the Qt animation support via QPropertyAnimation [2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html), which allows you to set the start and end times and values for a property, and then will automatically interpolate between them. See the documentation for usage examples. However, for your case as you are not animation a `QObject` subclass you cannot just this.

In general, if you need to perform a time consuming task, you should do so on a background thread to avoid blocking the UI thread, otherwise your app will freeze.